# Can I add recaptcha on my web form which is google form?

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha, google-forms, recaptcha-v3

I'm creating my first website reply form,
my reply form actually is connect google forms,
I have 3 forms in one page,
wanna add google recaptcha but not sure I'm doing right or not,
here's my code below, please help, thanks!!!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=my_site_key"></script>
</head>
<body>
            <iframe name="iframe_redirect" id="iframe_redirect" style="display:none;" onload="if(typeof sent_redirect!='undefined'){window.location='submitpage/';}"></iframe>
            <form action="my_google_forms_url" method="post" onsubmit="sent_redirect=true" target="iframe_redirect" id="form1">                
                <label for="Person1">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="Person1" name="entry.5176058000">
                <textarea name="entry.900000000"></textarea>            
            </form>

            <iframe name="iframe_redirect" id="iframe_redirect" style="display:none;" onload="if(typeof sent_redirect!='undefined'){window.location='submitpage/';}"></iframe>
            <form action="my_google_forms_url" method="post" onsubmit="sent_redirect=true" target="iframe_redirect" id="form2">                
                <label for="Person2">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="Person2" name="entry.5176058000">
                <textarea name="entry.900000000"></textarea>            
            </form>

            <iframe name="iframe_redirect" id="iframe_redirect" style="display:none;" onload="if(typeof sent_redirect!='undefined'){window.location='submitpage/';}"></iframe>
            <form action="my_google_forms_url" method="post" onsubmit="sent_redirect=true" target="iframe_redirect" id="form3">                
                <label for="Person3">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="Person2" name="entry.5176058000">
                <textarea name="entry.900000000"></textarea>            
            </form>

            
            <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitbutton" onclick="submitform()">
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
function submitform(){
    const Form1 = document.forms['form1'];
    const Form2 = document.forms['form2'];
    const Form3 = document.forms['form3'];
    let Person1 = Form1["entry.5176058000"];
    let Person2 = Form2["entry.5176058000"];
    let Person3 = Form3["entry.5176058000"];

    if( Person1.value === ""){
        alert('please fill the name');
    } else if( Person2.value === ""){
    alert('please fill the name');
    } else if( Person3.value === ""){
    alert('please fill the name');
    } else{
      function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
          grecaptcha.execute('my_site_key', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {
              verifyCallback(token)
          });
        });
      }
      function verifyCallback(token) {

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('token', token);

    fetch(uriGAS, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        if(result.success) {
                if(result.score > 0.5) {
                    Form1.submit();
                    Form2.submit();
                    Form3.submit();
                    window.location.assign("submitpage.com");
                } else {
                    alert('seems like a robot')
        }
      } else {
        window.alert(result['error-codes'][0])
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        window.alert(err)
    })
}
     }
```

Google Forms' Apps Script (not sure if I'm doing this right or not...sorry I'm new to coding)

```
function doPost(e) {

  var params = e.parameter;
  var token = params.token;
  
  var uri = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
  var data = {
    secret: 'my reCAPTCHA secret key',
    response: token, 
    remoteip: ip
  }
  
  var option = {
    method: 'post',
    payload: data
  };
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(uri, option);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(response).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  
}
```